# PHP date_format

Tags: php, yii

I have an array named $dataArray, i want to show all the array content in my View, but there's some problem when I echo the date. The error is:

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

Here's the code

```
foreach ($dataArray as $data){                                                          
   echo '<tr align="center">';
   echo '<td>';
   echo CHtml::encode($data->first_name);
   echo ' ';
   echo CHtml::encode($data->last_name);
   echo '</td>';
   echo '<td>';
   $date = ($data->join);
   echo date_format($date,'Y/m/d');
   echo '</td>';
   echo '<td>';
   echo CHtml::encode($data->last_login);
   echo '</td>';
   echo '<td>';
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: What error you get from it...?

Comment: _there's some problem_ - could you tell us what it is?

Comment: seems to me it should be $data->date?, the date is stored in the array if i m not mistaken?

Comment: sorry i forgot write the error. I'm already edit the case

Comment: yes Manquer, the date is stored in the $dataArray->join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `date_format`, you must first use the [date_create()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.format.php) method. Take a look at the examples on that page for reference.

```
$date = date_create($data->join);
echo date_format($date, 'Y/m/d');
```

OR

You can also the native [date()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($data->join));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php date() function

```
<?php  

      echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($date));

 php>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(    But thanks for the answer